# How to change the physical location of the publisher server with Merge Replication?

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge-replication

I have set up the merge replication between central server and multiple clients and its been working smoothly. Now I have a requirement in which we are planning to change the location of the central server and shift to other location.

What are the steps to be followed to make all clients to point to the new location?

Answer (score 0):

Think only one reasonable solution is re-create whole replication on publisher , next re-create subscribers jobs and sync from snapshot.